# Joomla 1.5. How to add Like / Dislike button on videos / images?

Tags: image, button, video, joomla, facebook-like

I'm useing Joomla 1.5 AllVideoShare (Version 1.2.4) extension.

**QUESTION PART 1**

I want to ask you how to make like button on videos thumbs/images? For example if user likes video clip or image he can click like button and It counts how many users like It. It can be simple like button or facebook button if possible. Also maybe possible to make Like / Dislike buttons (If user don't like this video/image he can dislike It)

Example where I want to place:
http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/268/likecp.png

This is my part of code where videos are publishing:

```
    <?php if ($this->params->get('show_'.$header, 1)) : ?>
    <h2> <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get($header)); ?> </h2>
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="avs_gallery2<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('pageclass_sfx')); ?>">
  <?php 
    if(!count($videos)) echo JText::_('ITEM_NOT_FOUND');
    for ($i=0, $n=count($videos); $i < $n; $i++) {   
        $clear = ''; 
        if($column >= $this->cols) {
            $clear  = '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
            $column = 0;
            $row++;     
        }
        $column++;
        echo $clear;
  ?>

    <span class="name"><?php echo $categories[$i]->name; ?></span> 
    <div id="testas" class="avs_thumb" style="width:190px;" onclick='javascript:location.href="<?php echo JRoute::_($link.$videos[$i]->slug.$qs); ?>"'> 
    <img class="arrow" src="<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>components/com_allvideoshare/assets/play.gif" border="0" style="margin-left:80px; margin-top:47px;" /> 
    <img class="image" src="<?php echo $videos[$i]->thumb; ?>" width="190; " height="120;" title="<?php echo JText::_('CLICK_TO_VIEW') . ' : ' . $videos[$i]->title; ?>" border="0" /> 
    <span class="title"><FONT COLOR="#000000"><?php echo $videos[$i]->title; ?></font></span> 
    <span class="views"><FONT COLOR="#000000"><?php echo JText::_('Peržiūros'); ?> : <strong><?php echo $videos[$i]->views*2+1; ?></strong></font></span> 
        <div class="avs_category_label"><?php echo JText::_('Kategorija'); ?> : <strong><?php echo $videos[$i]->category; ?></strong></div>


  </div>  

  <?php } ?>
```

**QUESTION PART 2**

After I add Like / Dislike buttons will be possible to sort them by "Most popular" (Which video have most likes) or there are so hard work?

Example: http://www.anekdotai.lt/

**QUESTION PART 3**

In the same place as Like / Dislike button I want to put Facebook share button. I have script which works, but I can't succesfully add It to this place.

FB Share script:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$linkTxt = $params->get( 'linkTxt', '' );
$linkColor = $params->get( 'linkColor', '' );
$linkHColor = $params->get( 'linkHColor', '' );
$theUrl = $params->get( 'theUrl', '1' );
$wholeUrl = "location.href.substring(0,location.href.lastIndexOf('/'))";
$currentUrl = "location.href";
?>

<script>function fbs_click() {u=<?php if($params->get('theUrl', 1))
        {
        echo $currentUrl;
        }
        else{
        echo $wholeUrl;
        } ?>;t=document.title;window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;}</script><style> html .fb_share_button { display: -moz-inline-block; display:inline-block; padding:1px 1px 1px 20px; height:17px; color:#<?php echo $linkColor ?>; background:url(http://static.ak.facebook.com/images/share/facebook_share_icon.gif?6:26981) no-repeat left; } html .fb_share_button:hover { color:#<?php echo $linkHColor ?>; background:url(http://static.ak.facebook.com/images/share/facebook_share_icon.gif?6:26981) no-repeat left; text-decoration:none; } </style> <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<url>" class="fb_share_button" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><?php echo $linkTxt; ?></a>
```

If I put It to Video publishing code I get error:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in ..../juokoera.lt/public_html/components/com_allvideoshare/views/videos/tmpl/default.php on line 26`

Thank you for answers.

Comment: what version of AllVideoShare do you have?

Comment: 1.2.4 Version of AllVideoShare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following code which will define the $params variable:

`$params = JComponentHelper::getParams( 'com_yourcomponent' );`